# Elements of Programming Interview: Buy and Sell A Stock Twice

Tags: optimization, algorithms, python

I am going through the book Elements of Programming Interview and have gotten stuck at the solution to the "Buy and Sell A Stock Twice" problem.

> Write a program that computes the maximum profit that can be made by
>   buying and selling a share at most twice. The second buy must be made
>   on another date after the first sale.

The solution is explained by the authors below:

> Suppose we record the best solution for A[0, j], j between 1 and n-1,
>   inclusive. Now we can do a reverse iteration, computing the best
>   solution for a single buy-and-sell for A[j, n-1], j between 1 and n-1,
>   inclusive. For each day, we combine this result with the result from
>   the forward iteration for the previous day- this yields the maximum
>   profit if we buy and sell once before the current day and once at or
>   after the current day. For example, suppose the input array is [12,
>   11, 13, 9, 12, 8, 14, 13, 15]. Then the most profit that can be made
>   with a single buy and sell by Day i (inclusive) is F = [0, 0, 2, 2, 3,
>   3, 6, 6, 7]. Working backwards the most profit that can be made with a
>   single buy and sell on or after Day i is B = [7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0]. To
>   combine these two, we compute m[i] - F[i - 1] + B[i], where F[-1] is
>   taken to be 0 (since the second buy must happen strictly after the
>   first sell. This yields M = [7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10, 5, 8, 6].

My Questions Are:

1. How is the algorithm working on a higher level. I do not understand why we are doing a reverse iteration at all. I understand the forward iteration, it simply gives you the most profit if you buy and sell 1 time.
2. Where is the equation M[i] = F[i - 1] + B[i] come from?
3. how are they obtaining B = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 0]? I tried to do the reverse iteration and arrive at entirely different values
4. By saying "between 1 and n - 1" inclusive, do they mean 1 and n-1 are included?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what the various arrays being used, i.e., $A[i,,j]$, $F[i]$, $B[i]$ and $M[i]$, are supposed to represent. However, it seem the book is using a technique called [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). This is a fairly general optimization technique where to find the best result at some future date, you iterate backwards from that date to find each optimal solution at $i$ based on the results at $i -1$.